# Stargazer variable headings for multiple linear models

Tags: r, model, regression, stargazer

I have multiple linear models with the same dependent variables (Y) and a varying explanatory variables that I need to summarize in a table. However, stargazer adds the same Ys to the heading for each group of explanatory variables making the table unnecessarily wide. Is there anyway I can prevent this?

```
# control dummies
jan <- a$january
mon <- a$monday




y1 <- a$1
y2 <- a$2
y3 <- a$3

x1 <- a$4
x2 <- a$5
x3 <- a$6
m11 <- lm(y1~x1+jan+mon)
m21 <- lm(y2~x1+jan+mon)
m21 <- lm(y3~x1+jan+mon) 
m12 .... .... m33
```

My current guess is that it's due to the fact that I don't specify the data = in the lm model and the fact that some of the explanatory variables have less observations.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it would be extremely helpful if you could simply paste the output you are seeing from stargazer here - otherwise we may simply not understand the issue you are facing (e.g., `y1`, `y2`, `y3` are not the same and, hence, stargazer would obviously not recognize them as being the same)

*Initial answer based on my understanding of your problem:*
For models that have the same dependent variable and are next to each other stargazer will automatically group the heading and won't report it twice:

Models with same DV that are next to each other

```
stargazer(model1, model1, model2, type = "text")

================================================================================
                                             Dependent variable:                
                              --------------------------------------------------
                                       daily_invcount2          daily_invcount3 
                                          negative                  negative    
                                          binomial                  binomial    
                                    (1)              (2)              (3)       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Models with same DV that are not next to each other

```
stargazer(model1, model2, model1, type = "text")

================================================================================
                                             Dependent variable:                
                              --------------------------------------------------
                              daily_invcount2  daily_invcount3  daily_invcount2 
                                  negative         negative         negative    
                                  binomial         binomial         binomial    
                                    (1)              (2)              (3)       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If this does not work for any particular reason stargazer offers three additional options:

- If the DV is the same across all models you can turn off the dep var labels with `dep.var.labels.include = FALSE` and modify the overarching caption to something like `dep.var.caption = "Dependent variable: DV 1"`
- If the DVs are different but are closely connected you could also edit the overarching dep var caption as above and overwrite the dep var labels with `dep.var.labels = c("option a", "option b")`
- Finally, you can turn off the dep var labels, and split your models into custom groups and add manually defined column labels with (values are exemplary) `column.separate = c(2, 1), column.labels = c("option a", "option b")`

  I will update this answer as soon as I fully understand your issue.